# Erro ao tentar gerar bundles com Webpack

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

Tem um projeto que utiliza webpack junto com nodejs e angular, mas ao tentar usar o comando "webpack" no terminal para gerar os bundles do webpack ele exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo de configuração do webpack (webpack.config.js):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack Config
var webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    'main': './src/main.browser.ts',
  },

  output: {
    publicPath: '',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      {
        // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
      }
    ),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),

  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // .ts files for TypeScript
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader',
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'angular2-router-loader'
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]
  }

};


// Our Webpack Defaults
var defaultConfig = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
    modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules') ]
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },

  node: {
    global: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }
};


module.exports = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema era na versão do webpack que eu estava usando, foi só instalar uma versão mais antiga que funcionou normalmente.

> npm install -g webpack@^3